# free-jqgrid with bootstrap and datepicker issue

Tags: javascript, datepicker, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am using demo sample located https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/90qmjean/3/

Some reason datepicker is not rendering? also i need to set dateformat to

```
ISO8601Long:"Y-m-d H:i:s"
```

But with original date formatter shows selected date as 'Y-3-14 H:i:s'
see the screenshot for details:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue23H.png)

Comment: If you need to enter/change the **time** together with the date, then you need probably [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) see [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/duooa5oy/1/)

Comment: Thanks Oleg for information!

Comment: Hi Oleg, Datetimepicker window does not close automatically after selecting date?

Comment: Could you describe the exact test case to reproduce the problem? The datetimepicker will be automatically closed on change of focus, for example on click on "Save" button or on click on another line.

Comment: Hi Oleg, The same issue is occurring on this demo url http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/duooa5oy/1/

Comment: Could you describe the exact test case to reproduce the problem?

Comment: When you select the date from datepicker, the datepicker window stays ON. It does not close automatically.

Comment: It would be good if you modify the text of your question to include the problem about closing the datetimepicker window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, which you described in comments above, is the following: you are wonder why the [Bootstrap datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), used in the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/duooa5oy/1/, don't close the calendar window after choosing the date.

First of all, I want to stress, that it's the *default behavior* of the Bootstrap datetime picker. You can try any demo on the page http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ to verify that. The reason of the behavior is easy to understand. The datetimepicker allows to change **the time** and not only the date. The corresponding control contains 4 buttons, which increase/decrease the time via click on the buttons. I marked the buttons on the picture below:

[image]

Thus, what you probably want is closing of the datetimepicker if **the date** (and not the time) is changed. One can implement the requirements by adding the following lines in the demo:

```
$(el).bind("dp.change", function (e) {
    if (e.date.dayOfYear() !== e.oldDate.dayOfYear()) {
        $(this).data("DateTimePicker").hide();
    }
});
```

See the modified date http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/duooa5oy/7/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when i updated boostrap-datepicker to latest version, it worked.